# How do i get the tab name in a usercontrol umbraco

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, umbraco

Does anyone know how to get the tabname of a contentpage? I know how to get the id but not how to get the name?
This is my code so far:

```
 int userId = umbraco.BasePages.UmbracoEnsuredPage.GetUserId(umbraco.BasePages.UmbracoEnsuredPage.umbracoUserContextID);  
           DocumentType typeToCreate = DocumentType.GetByAlias("FAQItem");

                Document newDoc = Document.MakeNew("test123", typeToCreate, new global::umbraco.BusinessLogic.User(userId), 1161);
                newDoc.getProperty("yourName").Value = newDoc.getProperty("Question");

                    foreach(var prop in newDoc.GenericProperties)
                    {
                        newDoc.getProperty("email").Value += prop.PropertyType.TabId + " ";
                    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed the same using .getVirtualTabs, something like:

```
foreach (var t in dt.getVirtualTabs())
 {
  if (t.Id == id)
  return t.Caption;
 }
```